# PVS Studio analysis

Tags: c++, static-analysis, pvs-studio

I have a project at university where i need to make a  static analysis on a project using any tool . 
I chose this project written in C++: https://github.com/AndreaOrru/LaiNES and PVS Studio tool (on linux). 
But, i have a problem. This project doesn't have a make or cmake file.. this project have a Sconstruct file .
It's posibile somehow to make analysis with pvs ? 
If it's not posible , what other tool should i use ?

Comment: https://www.viva64.com/en/m/0036/#ID0EFLAG

Answer (score 2):

According to PVS-Studio [docs](https://www.viva64.com/en/m/0036/#ID0EFLAG), you can capture compiler invocations via `pvs-studio-analyzer trace`:

`cd /path/to/LaiNES
 pvs-studio-analyzer trace -- scons`

After that, you can analyze the project and generate a "raw" log:

`pvs-studio-analyzer analyze -o /path/to/project.log -jN`

Then, convert the "raw" log into some format proper for you (e.g., QtCreator tasklist):

`plog-converter -a GA:1,2 -t tasklist -o /path/to/project.tasks /path/to/project.log`

Make sure that you've added special comments in LaiNES' compilation units before starting the analysis to [use PVS-Studio free](https://www.viva64.com/en/b/0614/).